# Issue with Administratively Assigned Offline Files

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy

I need to use Administratively Assigned Offline files in conjunction with folder redirection, but user home folders live on 26 different shares. Do I just need to add 52 file paths similar to:

> \\server\shareA\%username%\Desktop
>
> \\server\shareA\%username%\My Documents
>
> \\server\shareB\%username%\Desktop
>
> \\server\shareB\%username%\My Documents

... and so on? Or do I need to create 26 GPOs, one for each share; or is there an easier way to do it?

Edit: The solution provided by @berniewhite in the comments of using %homeshare% has resolved the issue and Administratively Assigned Offline Files is now working well.

Comment: Yeah, there is an easier way. Stop using 26 different shares and combine them all in one big share.

Comment: The shares are spread across a number of different volumes due to the amount of data being stored and the number of users with home directories.

Comment: User accounts can individually specify a home path. You can then use the home path in GPOs as a variable. I.e. %homepath% %homeshare% %homedrive%

Comment: @BernieWhite that does appear to be the solution to the issues that I am experiencing.

Comment: @BernieWhite if you put that in the Answers section I am more than happy to give you reputation for that comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have described is generally a two part process.

### 1. Configure the user’s %HOMESHARE% environment variable

The easiest way to do this on mass is to configure a `Connect To` `Home folder` in the `Profile` tab of the user account in Active Directory.

When a user logs on, the `%HOMESHARE%` will be set to the value of the `To:` and `%HOMEPATH%` will be set to `\`.

For example you might set this to:

```
Connect: H:
To: \\server1\homedrives\%username%
```

### 2. Configure the GPO

The second part is to use the environment variables in the GPO.

With a folder redirection GPO you would use something like:

`Basic—Redirect everyone's folder to the same location` for the Documents folder redirection, then use a combination of `%HOMESHARE%` `%HOMEPATH%` and `%HOMEDRIVE%` to point each user to a unique user location. E.g.

```
%HOMESHARE%%HOMEPATH%
```

This might help:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732275.aspx
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816313

Answer (score 0):

If you have enterprise licensing look into using a DFS namespace.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753479%28WS.10%29.aspx

From there the redirection should be easy.

Comment: DFS namespace may not work well if you have to balance shares over servers on a mass scale, because it would mean you would need to create each user folder as a leaf, which has its own overhead. You can't just do \\namespace\home\user in a single GPO. You would need to combine it with variables.

Comment: @BernieWhite - true. I didn't take the user balancing into consideration. I've predominantly used namespaces for combining multiple shares into a single interface as indicated.